# Using cp.Parameter does not obtain the speedup claimed in the cvxpy doc

Tags: python, optimization, cvxpy

I am trying to use cvxpy to solve an integer linear program (ILP). As I need to run the same ILP (with different parameter matrix) several thousand times to solve my problem, I need to improve the runtime.

One approach provided in the tutorial is using `cp.Parameter` for the parameter in the program without repeatedly constructing the same `cp.Problem` (see [cvxpy tutorial](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/intro/index.html#parameters)). Based on this, one could use `multiprocessing` library to exploit the power of multiple processors.

However, when I tried to compare two versions of simple regression problems (one with the use of `cp.Parameter` and one without), **I could not see the speedup claimed in the tutorial**:

> The purpose of parameters is to change the value of a constant in a problem without reconstructing the entire problem. In many cases, solving a parametrized program multiple times can be substantially faster than repeatedly solving a new problem.

The runtime of two versions of code is the following

```
successfully solved problem 10 / 10 times...
func: 'solveWithParam' args: [(500, 400), {}] took: 21.6852 sec
successfully solved problem 10 / 10 times...
func: 'solveWithoutParam' args: [(500, 400), {}] took: 16.2620 sec
```

The code I used to obtain this result is the following

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp

from functools import wraps
from time import time

def timing(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        ts = time()
        result = f(*args, **kwargs)
        te = time()
        print("func: %r args: [%r, %r] took: %2.4f sec" % \
              (f.__name__, args, kwargs, te-ts))
        return result
    return wrap

@timing
def solveWithParam(m, n, K=10):
    np.random.seed(0)

    x = cp.Variable(n)
    A = cp.Parameter((m, n))
    b = cp.Parameter(m)

    objective = cp.Minimize(cp.sum_squares(A @ x - b))
    constraints = [0 <= x, x <= 1]
    problem = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)

    cnt = 0
    for _ in range(K):
        A.value = np.random.rand(m, n)
        b.value = np.random.rand(m)
        problem.solve()

        if problem.status == cp.OPTIMAL: cnt += 1
    
    print("successfully solved problem %d / %d times..." % (cnt, K))

@timing
def solveWithoutParam(m, n, K=10):
    np.random.seed(0)
    
    cnt = 0
    for _ in range(K):
        x = cp.Variable(n)
        A = np.random.rand(m, n)
        b = np.random.rand(m)

        objective = cp.Minimize(cp.sum_squares(A @ x - b))
        constraints = [0 <= x, x <= 1]
        problem = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)

        problem.solve()

        if problem.status == cp.OPTIMAL: cnt += 1
    
    print("successfully solved problem %d / %d times..." % (cnt, K))


m = 500
n = 400

solveWithParam(m, n)
solveWithoutParam(m, n)
```

I am not sure what I missed here, does this because the problem in this case is too simple?

Comment: 1) This functionality is about saving ime in regards to model-construction which means: DCP-ruleset + transformations. In most cases this is dominated by solving time. The solver won't care at all about this as it just sees one problem after another without any information to re-use. In short: not much to exploit here. 2) In regards to your experiment: it's quite useless as we don't know what's happening. There is no solver selected which means it could be a commercial one as CPLEX but also open-source one as GLPK. IP-solvers are very heuristic and hard to benchmark (rng, builtin-multicore...)

Comment: Also: it doesn't help that you are talking about linear integer programs but are showing continuous QPs / SOCPS. Especially within cvxpy as backend-selection- and transformation is a huge part of it's job. --- Summary: A: Only expect gains where cvxpy's model-building is costly! B: Improve benchmarks if eval is needed (random-permutations; statistics/outlier analysis; same-path/defaults-working checks)

Comment: @sascha Thank you! You are right. It seems that I am comparing apples (continues optimization) to pears (ILP). But in my ILP code, I am using Gurobi (after comparing its runtime with CPLEX). At the same time what do you mean by Summary B?

Comment: In B, i just tried to emphasize that your benchmark is not really suited as lots of stuff could lead to strange timings (prints/io in measured parts; garbage-collection and so on). As this is hard, a real scientific benchmark would need much more stastistics and other components to be more precise (e.g. random permutations -> might matter which experiment is done first).Additionally, more strange stuff can happen due to commercial solvers being quite aggressively in regards to your resources:"i see 4 cores; i will use 4 cores. don't care if you are hiding multiproc from me"

Comment: @sascha Thanks! Really helpful.

Comment: If you really need to improve performance that much, i'm afraid you will have to drop cvxpy and go for the lower-level solver APIs. There is then lots of potential to speed up things at the cost of missing out on cvxpy's help. Your use-case is vague, but when you got more control of your solver, you might use things like IP-warm-starting from partial/full solution (candidates). Compared to LPs, warm-starting in IP is more hard (due to losing lots of duality), but there are still many concepts helping *in some use-cases*. But all that is hard to achieve when being restricted to high-lvl cvxpy

Comment: @sascha As you suggested, I tried Gurobi's Python API (i.e. `gurobipy`) and re-implemented the ILP. However, maybe because I am not implementing it efficiently, the runtime is actually much **worse**. Could you take a look at my question [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/5464/4684).